# Javascript array resets on reloading

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm new to Javascript and have run into a problem. I have a Javascript file that I have linked to one HTML file, it worked fine when I used it for only one function but now that I have added a second extremely similar function it has ceased working, I have trawled through it several times and cannot determine why it would stop working. My HTML file is as follows.

```
<head>
<title>Programming Aptitude Test-Question One</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="AnswerStorage.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Question One</h1>

<ul>
    <li>a=10</li>
    <li>b=20</li>
    <li>a=b</li>
    <li>b=a</li>
    <li>What is the value of a?</li>
    <li>What is the value of b?</li>
</ul>

<p>Please enter your answer in the form "a=?, b=?", press submit only once when you are happy with your answer and click "next question" to go to the next page</p>

<p>Enter your answer:
    <input type="text" id="firstAnswer" />
</p>

<p>
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
</p>

<h1>Question Two</h1>

<p>What is a word to describe "walking cautiously"?</p>

<p>Enter your answer:
    <input type="text" id="redundantAnswer" />
</p>

<p>
    <input type="button" id="btnRedundant" value="Submit" />
</p>

<h1>Question Three</h1>

<p>Writ down as many words as you can associate with the word "Career."</p>

<p>Enter your answer:
    <input type="text" id="redundantAnswer" />
</p>

<p>
    <input type="button" id="btnRedundant" value="Submit" />
</p>

<h1>Question Four</h1>

<ul>
    <li>a=5</li>
    <li>b=6</li>
    <li>a=b</li>
    <li>b=a</li>
    <li>What is the value of a?</li>
    <li>What is the value of b?</li>
</ul>

<p>Please enter your answer in the form "a=?, b=?", press submit only once when you are happy with your answer and click "next question" to go to the next page</p>

<p>Enter your answer:
    <input type="text" id="secondAnswer" />
</p>

<p>
    <input type="button" id="secondButton" value="Submit" onclick=(secondCheck()) />
</p>



<a href="Question2.html">Next Question</a>

<p id="result"></p>
```

and my Javascript file is as follows, but my array is not printing and therefore I have no way of knowing if the elements are being added to it

```
var answers = [];
var result = document.getElementById("result");


function init() {
var myButton = document.getElementById("btnSubmit");
myButton.onclick = firstCheck;

}

onload = init;


function firstCheck()

{

var theFirstAnswer = document.getElementById("firstAnswer").value.toLowerCase();
var message = "";


var success = false;

if (newName == "")

{

    alert("Please, enter an answer");

    return false;

}

if (theFirstAnswer == "a=0, b=20") {
    answers.push("m1");
    answers.push("s1");
}

if (theFirstAnswer == "a=20, b=20") {
    answers.push("m2");
    answers.push("s1");
}

if (theFirstAnswer == "a=10, b=0") {
    answers.push("m3");
    answers.push("s1");
}

if (theFirstAnswer == "a=10, b=10") {
    answers.push("m4");
    answers.push("s1");
}

if (theFirstAnswer == "a=30, b=50") {
    answers.push("m5");
    answers.push("s1");
}

if (theFirstAnswer == "a=0, b=30") {
    answers.push("m6");
    answers.push("s1");
}
if (theFirstAnswer == "a=40, b=30") {
    answers.push("m7");
    answers.push("s1");
}
if (theFirstAnswer == "a=30, b=0") {
    answers.push("m8");
    answers.push("s1");
}
if (theFirstAnswer == "a=10, b=20") {
    answers.push("m9");
    answers.push("m10");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theFirstAnswer == "a=20, b=10") {
    answers.push("m10");
    answers.push("s1");
}
if (theFirstAnswer == "a=0, b=10") {
    answers.push("m1");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theFirstAnswer == "a=20, b=0") {
    answers.push("m3");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theFirstAnswer == "a=10, b=30") {
    answers.push("m5");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theFirstAnswer == "a=30, b=20") {
    answers.push("m7");
    answers.push("s2");
}


for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++)

{


    if (answers[i] == theFirstAnswer)

    {

        message = "Sorry, the answer " + answers[i] + " has already been tried.  Try again";

        result.innerHTML = message;

        success = false;

        return false;

    } else

    {

        message = "Great, you've successfully registered with us as " + theFirstAnswer;

        result.innerHTML = message;

        success = true;

    }

}


if (success)

{

    answers.push(theFirstAnswer);

}


result.innerHTML += "<br />" + answers.sort();

}




function secondCheck()

{



var success = false;

var theSecondAnswer = document.getElementById("secondAnswer").value.toLowerCase();
var message = "";


var success = false;

if (theSecondAnswer == "")

{

    alert("Please, enter an answer");

    return false;

}

if (theSecondAnswer == "a=0, b=6") {
    answers.push("m1");
    answers.push("s1");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=6, b=6") {
    answers.push("m2");
    answers.push("s1");
    answers.push("m4");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=5, b=0") {
    answers.push("m3");
    answers.push("s1");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=5, b=5") {
    answers.push("m4");
    answers.push("s1");
    answers.push("m2");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=11, b=17") {
    answers.push("m5");
    answers.push("s1");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=0, b=11") {
    answers.push("m6");
    answers.push("s1");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=16, b=11") {
    answers.push("m7");
    answers.push("s1");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=11, b=0") {
    answers.push("m8");
    answers.push("s1");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=5, b=6") {
    answers.push("m9");
    answers.push("m10");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=6, b=5") {
    answers.push("m10");
    answers.push("s1");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=0, b=5") {
    answers.push("m1");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=6, b=0") {
    answers.push("m3");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=5, b=11") {
    answers.push("m5");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=11, b=6") {
    answers.push("m7");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=0, b=9, c=0") {
    answers.push("m1");
    answers.push("s1");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=9, b=9, c=9") {
    answers.push("m2");
    answers.push("s1");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=10, b=0, c=0") {
    answers.push("m3");
    answers.push("s1");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=10, b=7, c=10") {
    answers.push("m4");
    answers.push("s1");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=16, b=25, c=26") {
    answers.push("m5");
    answers.push("s1");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=0, b=16, c=0") {
    answers.push("m6");
    answers.push("s1");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=33, b=16, c=10") {
    answers.push("m7");
    answers.push("s1");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=26, b=0, c=0") {
    answers.push("m8");
    answers.push("s1");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=7, b=9, c=10") {
    answers.push("m9");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=10, b=9, c=7") {
    answers.push("m10");
    answers.push("s1");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=0, b=9, c=7") {
    answers.push("m1");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=7, b=9, c=7") {
    answers.push("m2");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=10, b=9, c=0") {
    answers.push("m3");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=10, b=9, c=10") {
    answers.push("m4");
    answers.push("s2");
}
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=7, b=9, c=17") {
    answers.push("m5");
    answers.push("s2");

    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=0, b=9, c=17") {
        answers.push("m6");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=17, b=9, c=10") {
        answers.push("m7");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=17, b=9, c=0") {
        answers.push("m8");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=9, b=7, c=0") {
        answers.push("m1");
        answers.push("s1");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=9, b=7, c=9") {
        answers.push("m2");
        answers.push("s1");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=0, b=0, c=25") {
        answers.push("m3");
        answers.push("s1");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=25, b=25, c=25") {
        answers.push("m4");
        answers.push("s1");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=41, b=39, c=9") {
        answers.push("m5");
        answers.push("s1");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=9, b=32, c=0") {
        answers.push("m6");
        answers.push("s1");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=57, b=32, c=66") {
        answers.push("m7");
        answers.push("s1");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=0, b=0, c=41") {
        answers.push("m8");
        answers.push("s1");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=25, b=7, c=9") {
        answers.push("m9");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=9, b=7, c=25") {
        answers.push("m10");
        answers.push("s1");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=0, b=7, c=25") {
        answers.push("m3");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=25, b=7, c=25") {
        answers.push("m4");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=34, b=7, c=9") {
        answers.push("m5");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=34, b=7, c=0") {
        answers.push("m6");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=25, b=7, c=34") {
        answers.push("m7");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=0, b=7, c=34") {
        answers.push("m8");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=-15") {
        answers.push("m1");
        answers.push("m2");
        answers.push("m10");
        answers.push("s1");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=0") {
        answers.push("m3");
        answers.push("m8");
        answers.push("s1");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=-6") {
        answers.push("m4");
        answers.push("m7");
        answers.push("m9");
        answers.push("s1");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "a=-21") {
        answers.push("m5");
        answers.push("m6");
        answers.push("s1");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "b=0") {
        answers.push("m1");
        answers.push("m6");
        answers.push("s1");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "b=-4") {
        answers.push("m2");
        answers.push("m5");
        answers.push("m9");
        answers.push("s1");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "b=-23") {
        answers.push("m3");
        answers.push("m4");
        answers.push("m10");
        answers.push("s1");
        answers.push("s2");
    }
    if (theSecondAnswer == "b=-27") {
        answers.push("m7");
        answers.push("m8");
        answers.push("s1");
        answers.push("s2");
    }



    for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++)

    {

        if (answers[i] == theSecondAnswer)

        {

            message = "Sorry, the answer " + answers[i] + " has already been attempted.  Try again";

            result.innerHTML = message;


            success = false;


            return false;

        } else

        {

            message = "Great, you've successfully registered with us as " + newName;

            result.innerHTML = message;


            success = true;

        }

    }



    if (success)

    {

        answers.push(theSecondAnswer);

    }


    result.innerHTML += "<br />" + answers.sort();

}
```

Sorry for what is likely an obvious error guys and I thank ye for your time in looking this over.

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: A little advice here, avoid pasting huge section of code because it scares people away even if they want to help you. Try using something like jsfiddle and gradually remove blocks of code as long as the problem is still there, until you cannot remove any more code to reproduce the problem. If you still can't see where the problem is, provide your much refined code here so people can help with much more ease. Also learn to use developer tools like browser consoles, which can help you catch obvious syntax errors etc.

Comment: Thank you very very much for the advice I will do absolutely it should make life much easier I expect and avoid the likes of the missing bracket underneath, I had not known about this, thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 3):

I think `}` is missing

```
if (theSecondAnswer == "a=7, b=9, c=17") {
    answers.push("m5");
    answers.push("s2");
} // <====  This is missing
```

You can use online tool such as [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to format your document, they also help in identifying errors

Comment: Thank you so much can't believe I missed that! Thanks a million, I've amended that but unfortunately the problem persists, thank you so so much for your response though it's sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Also in the HTML there is this:  `onclick=(secondCheck())`.

Comment: @JasonSperske, Its very long file, glad you identified it

Comment: And then this line: `if (newName == "") {` I think the meant `if (theFirstAnswer == "") {`, This is what jumped out while making a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yx4Uu/, it would help to break this problem up into simpler steps and only add code as they see each code addition work.

Comment: Thank you so so much that jsfiddle tool is amazing as once I finally get this functional css will be my next step so that will be incredibly useful thank you so much. If you guys dont mind my asking what is wrong with the onclick=(secondCheck()) line?